# Google Content Shopping API - how to get specific product by id?

Tags: google-ads-api, google-shopping-api

I can list products from Content Shopping API by

```
  var products = ShoppingContent.Products.list(merchantId, {
      pageToken: pageToken,
      maxResults: maxResults
    });
```

How about getting a specific product by using ID? Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

For a specific product, you have to use the [get](https://developers.google.com/shopping-content/v2/reference/v2/products/get) method.